# flight trip status bar implementation in angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular

hi folks i need to implement a flight trips status bar in angular.

1. If it's a continued trip (Eg. Bangalore to Chennai, Chennai to Ooty) then the straight line should be on level 1

2 If it's not a continued trip (Eg Bangalore to Chennai, Ooty to Bangalore) then the straight line should have an arrow and be on level 1.

3. If consecutive trips have the same pickup and drop location then those to be in Level 2
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCGA2.png)

Answer (score 0):

When we want to "connect" differents elements, we can use a SVG.

First we can defined you data. I imagine toy has an array like

```
trips = [
    { text: 'BLR-MAA', level: 1 },
    { text: 'MAA-HYD', level: 1 },
    { text: 'BLR-HYD', level: 1 },
    { text: 'HYB-DEL', level: 0 },
    { text: 'HYB-DEL', level: 0 },
    { text: 'DEL-BLR', level: 1 },
  ];
```

I number the levels from top (0 the most upper) to bottom

You can has, then

```
 <div #wrapper class="wrapper">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let trip of trips; let i = index">
      <div
        #airport
        class="airport"
        [style.padding-top.px]="trip.level * 50"
      >
        {{ trip.text }}
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
```

Where

```
.wrapper{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  min-height: 68px;
}
.wrapper::after{
  content:' '
}
.airport
{
  width:80px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

To draw the svg we need create a series of "path". This paths need know the with of the elements and the widht of the wrapper this is the reason we need

```
@ViewChild('wrapper') wrapper:ElementRef
@ViewChild('airport') airport:ElementRef
```

The "funny" is create the function that return an array of paths

```
getPaths()
  {
    const rect=this.wrapper.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    let width=this.airport.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().width
    const space=(rect.width-width*this.trips.length)/(this.trips.length)
    width=width+space
    const paths = [];

    this.trips.forEach((trip, i) => {
      if (i) {
        const fromY = this.trips[i - 1].level * 50+1; //add 1 to to allow showed the line
        const fromX = i * width - space;
        const toY = trip.level * 50+1; //add 1 to allow showed the line
        const toX = i *width;

        if (trip.level == this.trips[i - 1].level) {
          paths.push(
            'M' + fromX + ',' + fromY + ' L' + (toX) + ',' + toY
          );
        } else {
          const middle=(fromX+toX)/2)
          paths.push(
            'M' + fromX + ',' + fromY + ' C' + middle + ',' + fromY+
            ' '+middle+','+toY+' '+toX+','+toY
          );
        }
      }
    });
    return paths;
  }
}
```

See that is two adjacents elements are in the same level we create a line (we use M to move to the origin and L to draw the line

If two adjacents elements are in a different level we create a curve (we use M to move to the origin and C to create the curve)

The last in create the svg enclosed in a div with position absolute and all in a div with position relative

```
<div style="position:relative">
  <div #wrapper class="wrapper">
    ...
  </div>
  <div style="position:absolute;top:.5rem">
    <svg stroke="red" fill="transparent" [attr.width]="wrapper.offsetWidth" 
             [attr.heigth]="wrapper.offsetHeight" >
      <path *ngFor="let path of paths" [attr.d]="path" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

See how we give the same width and heigth to our svg using the template reference variable "wrapper" and offsetHeigth/offsetWidth

a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-paginator-with-goto-ffafek?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)